# How to install pip on debian with python 2.7?

Tags: python, pip, debian, virtualbox, setuptools

I read many website and question-answer, but i get always the same error, and nowhere I can't find the solution.
My errors:

Errors while processings:
`python error python-crypto python-wheel python-pkg-resources python-keyrings.alt ptho-dbus python-pip python-xdg python-secretstorage python-keyring E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)`.

I installed Python 2.7.13 to /usr/src/Python2.7.13

Any ideas?

Edit - Beomi :

```
sudo apt-get update   -- done, working
sudo apt-get upgrade  -- not working, i get the errors what i wrote
sudo apt-get -f install -- not working, i get the errors what i wrote
```

I installed Python 2.7.13 following this link: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/#

Edit2 - Beomi :

```
web@debian:/usr/src/Python-2.7.13$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Beállítás: python-crypto (2.6.1-7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: error processing package python-crypto (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alfolyamat 1 hibakóddal kilépett
Beállítás: python-wheel (0.29.0-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: error processing package python-wheel (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alfolyamat 1 hibakóddal kilépett
dpkg: error processing package python-pkg-resources (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-keyrings.alt:
 python-keyrings.alt függőségek: python-crypto; ám:
  python-crypto csomag még beállítatlan.

dpkg: error processing package python-keyrings.alt (--configure):
 függőségi hibák - e csomag beállítatlan maradt
Beállítás: python-dbus (1.2.4-1+b1) ...
Remove stale byte-compiled files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: error processing package python-dbus (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alfolyamat 1 hibakóddal kilépett
Beállítás: python-pip (9.0.1-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alfolyamat 1 hibakóddal kilépett
Beállítás: python-xdg (0.25-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 26, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
dpkg: error processing package python-xdg (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alfolyamat 1 hibakóddal kilépett
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-secretstorage:
 python-secretstorage függőségek: python-dbus; ám:
  python-dbus csomag még beállítatlan.

dpkg: error processing package python-secretstorage (--configure):
 függőségi hibák - e csomag beállítatlan maradt
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-keyring:
 python-keyring függőségek: python-dbus; ám:
  python-dbus csomag még beállítatlan.
 python-keyring függőségek: python-secretstorage; ám:
  python-secretstorage csomag még beállítatlan.

dpkg: error processing package python-keyring (--configure):
 függőségi hibák - e csomag beállítatlan maradt
Hibák történtek a feldolgozáskor:
 python-crypto
 python-wheel
 python-pkg-resources
 python-keyrings.alt
 python-dbus
 python-pip
 python-xdg
 python-secretstorage
 python-keyring
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Check this [link](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/) for more info

EDIT:

Check [This](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs) as well. This is important to know.

Edit :
Try this ([src](http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-pip-linux.html))

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

also This ([src](https://tecadmin.net/install-pip-linux/))

```
$ curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"

$ python get-pip.py
```

Comment: The link says **Warning Recent Debian/Ubuntu versions have modified pip to use the “User Scheme” by default, which is a significant behavior change that can be surprising to some users**

Comment: In which part i have to try?

Comment: Or try this :
**sudo apt-get install python-pip**

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-pip : i get the same error ; 
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py" : there isnt curl, so i tried with sudo wget, but after runnin get-pip.py i get Syntax Error...lol..

Comment: Then I would suggest to go through the second link.There are the possible way you can install. Or download it and run the setup.  This is the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev &&
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tar.xz &&
tar -xvf Python-2.7.13.tar.xz &&
cd Python-2.7.13 &&
./configure && sudo make && sudo make install
```

Comment: Not simply like that. I tried this method too, but i get the same error message. :(

Comment: try `purging` python and installing again

Comment: with 'sudo apt-get remove python2.7' ?

Comment: `apt-get purge python` but it's dangerous!

Comment: i tried with this: sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-debian but the result is the same error message again....

Comment: That's why i wrote this question, because i tried all, and i get always this error message again and again.. :S

Answer (score 0):

As your question doesn't include what you have done so far..

so, How about fix your apt packages first?

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and then try again with `sudo`.

> And one more: How about install python with `sudo apt-get install python`?
>
> If you really need latest version of python 2.7, plz tell in question/comment.

If not working, please update question and comment plz.

-- Update --

As `sudo apt-get upgrade` not working, I thought there'd be problem with `PATH`, system default python vs new-installed python.

-- Update --

It could be problem of debian iso file.

Comment: which python : i get this --> /usr/bin/python

Comment: So when you exec `python`, then it is system default python, not python you 've installed. Let me think just more..

Comment: can you tell me result of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ?

Comment: would you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7` ? this command will install python2.7 with pure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155890/discussion-between-beomi-and-harley).

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called get_pip.py in the python 2.7 , can you ran that and check ? python get_pip.py in the target machine.

Comment: No, there isn't